# Determine why sendmail is failing to send

Tags: sendmail

I have a form on a webpage that sends an email using sendmail on the same server. The recipient is a client that uses Google Apps for their email. In the form, I enter my email address. If I enter ***@aol.com** or ***@yahoo.com** (where "*" is anything, not a literal asterisk, of course), the email fails to send with the following dump in `/var/log/mail.log`:

```
Sep 22 14:01:12 localhost sendmail[16522]: t8ME1CSU016522: Authentication-Warning: localhost.local: www-data set sender to no_reply@robwilkerson.org using -f
Sep 22 14:01:12 localhost sendmail[16522]: t8ME1CSU016522: from=no_reply@robwilkerson.org, size=1099, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201509221401.t8ME1CSU016522@localhost.local>, relay=www-data@localhost
Sep 22 14:01:12 localhost sm-mta[16523]: t8ME1CIi016523: from=<no_reply@robwilkerson.org>, size=1418, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201509221401.t8ME1CSU016522@localhost.local>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost.local [127.0.0.1]
Sep 22 14:01:12 localhost sendmail[16522]: t8ME1CSU016522: to=recruitment@robwilkerson.org, ctladdr=no_reply@robwilkerson.org (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=31099, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (t8ME1CIi016523 Message accepted for delivery)
Sep 22 14:01:12 localhost sendmail[16527]: t8ME1CjK016527: Authentication-Warning: localhost.local: www-data set sender to no_reply@robwilkerson.org using -f
Sep 22 14:01:12 localhost sendmail[16527]: t8ME1CjK016527: from=no_reply@robwilkerson.org, size=1224, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201509221401.t8ME1CjK016527@localhost.local>, relay=www-data@localhost
Sep 22 14:01:12 localhost sm-mta[16528]: t8ME1CK4016528: from=<no_reply@robwilkerson.org>, size=1543, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201509221401.t8ME1CjK016527@localhost.local>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost.local [127.0.0.1]
Sep 22 14:01:12 localhost sendmail[16527]: t8ME1CjK016527: to=marketing@robwilkerson.org, ctladdr=no_reply@robwilkerson.org (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=31224, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (t8ME1CK4016528 Message accepted for delivery)
Sep 22 14:01:13 localhost sm-mta[16530]: STARTTLS=client, relay=aspmx.l.google.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256, bits=128/128
Sep 22 14:01:13 localhost sm-mta[16525]: STARTTLS=client, relay=aspmx.l.google.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256, bits=128/128
Sep 22 14:01:13 localhost sm-mta[16530]: t8ME1CK4016528: to=<marketing@robwilkerson.org>, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=121543, relay=aspmx.l.google.com. [173.194.205.27], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
Sep 22 14:01:13 localhost sm-mta[16530]: t8ME1CK4016528: t8ME1DK4016530: DSN: Service unavailable
Sep 22 14:01:13 localhost sm-mta[16530]: t8ME1DK4016530: to=<no_reply@robwilkerson.org>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=30000, relay=aspmx.l.google.com. [173.194.205.27], dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
Sep 22 14:01:13 localhost sm-mta[16530]: t8ME1DK4016530: t8ME1DK5016530: return to sender: User unknown
Sep 22 14:01:13 localhost sm-mta[16530]: t8ME1DK5016530: to=root, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=30000, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
Sep 22 14:01:13 localhost sm-mta[16525]: t8ME1CIi016523: to=<recruitment@robwilkerson.org>, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=121418, relay=aspmx.l.google.com. [173.194.205.27], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
Sep 22 14:01:13 localhost sm-mta[16525]: t8ME1CIi016523: t8ME1DIi016525: DSN: Service unavailable
Sep 22 14:01:13 localhost sm-mta[16525]: t8ME1DIi016525: to=<no_reply@robwilkerson.org>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=30000, relay=aspmx.l.google.com. [173.194.205.27], dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
Sep 22 14:01:13 localhost sm-mta[16525]: t8ME1DIi016525: t8ME1DIj016525: return to sender: User unknown
Sep 22 14:01:13 localhost sm-mta[16525]: t8ME1DIj016525: to=root, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=30000, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
```

Every other email address that I've tried seems to work fine and the logs indicate success. Both seem to connect to the relay, but the failures fall apart right after that.

I can see that a service is unavailable, but I'm not entirely sure which one nor am I sure why it's only unavailable when I enter those addresses - especially when the sender is being forced to a `no_reply` email address. Why would the value I enter on the form matter at all? I'm clearly missing something.

I'm not a sysadmin and I'm certainly not well-versed in email troubleshooting so I'm hoping someone can give me a hand understanding what I'm looking at here. What could be causing these failures?

Comment: What makes you think the destination address(es) exist?  `recruitment@myclient.com` also gives me a bounce, from google, as does `marketing@myclient.com`.

Comment: Sorry, `myclient.com` is a placeholder. I didn't want to publish the actual client address. I know it works because email arrives when sent in non-yahoo, non-aol cases.

Comment: I **very** strongly advise you to read [the meta post on whether and how to obfuscate information](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/963/what-information-should-i-include-or-obfuscate-in-my-posts) - and tell us everything about the problem, not just what you think we should need.

Comment: Fair enough and point taken. In this case, I'm just looking for help understanding what these logs are telling me. I know the end result: the email send recorded here fails. I don't know how to read these logs well enough to understand why or where to look next.

Comment: I also know that the same email _does_ send if I enter non-aol, non-yahoo info on the form.

Comment: You can send to yourself? post the full information from your message headers, feel free to switch out domains with example.com and example.net

Answer (score 2):

## Sendmail: send a test message with full SMTP transcript

You can make sendmail send a test message with full transcript of the SMTP session.
Usually it provides more clues why delivery fails.

Execute the following script as root after changing SENDER and RECIPIENT.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
SENDER=jd@example.net
ENVELOPE_SENDER=$SENDER
RECIPIENT=jd@example.com

/usr/sbin/sendmail -i -v -f$ENVELOPE_SENDER -- $RECIPIENT <<END
from: $SENDER
to: $RECIPIENT
subject: delivery test

Delivery test -- ignore it.
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Signup for feedback loops and find out from aol and yahoo, also make sure you are complaint.

- http://postmaster.yahoo.com/
- https://postmaster.aol.com/

make sure you respect NDR's (which I see a few), you might also want to use a smarthost like sendgrid to help you out.

Comment: I'm waiting on confirmation, but I was told that the app in question did send the email with a from address entered on the form. That would lead me to believe that DMARC is the problem. The messages weren't originating from the yahoo/aol servers.

Comment: Send an email to your gmail account and post the headers from 'view original' that may help too